# Extract part of txt file

Tags: powershell, extract

I have a very large text file and I would like to extract specific columns of the text file that start with a specific pattern to an xls file preferably. The data I would like to extract start with a track id number (i.e. Track ID=20). I would like to be able to read the track ID number and then store some of the info given below and then do it again for the next track ID etc. I searched online and figured it should be possible using PowerShell on Windows.

Below the image  is a small part of the text. In this instance I want to keep the ID number which is 13 and also the columns Z(mm) and KinE(MeV).

```
* G4Track Information:   Particle = proton,   Track ID = 13,   Parent ID = 0
*********************************************************************************************************

Step#    X(mm)    Y(mm)    Z(mm) KinE(MeV)  dE(MeV) StepLeng TrackLeng  NextVolume ProcName
    0        0        0 1.08e+03      100         0        0         0       World initStep
    1        0        0      800      100     3e-23      280       280     Tracker Transportation
    2        0        0      450      100  3.75e-23      350       630        Film StepLimiter    
    3        0        0      438     87.1      12.9       12       642        Film hIoni  
    4   -0.204   -0.136      429     76.7      10.4     9.42       651        Film hIoni
    5   -0.422   -0.104      421     67.3      9.43     7.53       659        Film hIoni
    6   -0.679  -0.0754      415     59.3      7.94     5.98       665        Film hIoni
    7   -0.899   -0.128      410     52.3      7.05     4.81       670        Film hIoni
    8    -1.01   -0.141      406     45.7       6.6     3.86       674        Film hIoni
    9    -1.04   -0.168      403     40.3      5.39     3.06       677        Film hIoni
   10     -1.1   -0.203      401     35.3      4.96     2.47       679        Film hIoni
   11    -1.13   -0.218      399     30.6      4.65     1.98       681        Film hIoni
   12    -1.16   -0.191      397     26.6      4.03     1.57       683        Film hIoni
   13    -1.21   -0.154      396     23.2       3.4     1.25       684        Film hIoni
   14    -1.26   -0.141      395       20      3.21     1.01       685        Film hIoni
   15     -1.3   -0.129      394     17.1       2.9    0.812       686        Film hIoni
   16    -1.34   -0.115      394     14.4      2.74    0.651       686        Film hIoni
   17    -1.31   -0.108      393     12.1      2.32    0.517       687        Film hIoni
   18    -1.29    -0.12      393     9.74      2.32    0.418       687        Film hIoni
   19    -1.28    -0.13      392     7.56      2.18    0.332       688        Film hIoni
   20    -1.27   -0.142      392     5.41      2.15    0.261       688        Film hIoni
   21    -1.27   -0.152      392     3.07      2.34    0.199       688        Film hIoni
   22    -1.28   -0.156      392    0.285      2.78    0.118       688        Film hIoni
   23    -1.28   -0.157      392        0     0.285  0.00319       688        Film hIoni

*********************************************************************************************************
```

[image: part of the txt file]

```
$log = Get-Content C:\Users\kpapa\Desktop\kkk.txt
foreach ($line in $log) { 
    if ($line -like "*878*") { 
        $line | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\kpapa\Desktop\kkkk.xls" -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal working example. Show us what you have tried so far. We won't code for you!

Comment: It is possible with PowerShell. So either you learn PowerShell or hire someone to do it for you - SO isn'a free script writing service. An off topic [software recommendation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhDMqBuJcKE&feature=youtu.be&msrc=website-Monarch-Product)

Comment: Could you let me know of some tutorial to learn powershell. So far i have built a small powershell script that detects specific characters on a line and then exports to excel.
`$log = get-content C:\Users\kpapa\Desktop\kkk.txt
foreach ($line in $log) { 
    if ($line -like "*878*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "C:\Users\kpapa\Desktop\kkkk.xls" -Append
    }
}`

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. Without line breaks it's hardy readable. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50305166/edit) your question to include the code. Images are not helpful to reproduce your situation - insert plain text for this (neutralized if confidential). Does the `Track ID` occur only in the file or multiple times? Is the line always prepended with `* G4Track....` ?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to relate to your question in any way.

Comment: @lotPings Excuse me for the format of my question. As for what you noticed, yes the line always prepends with *G4Track. However Track ID occurs multiple times in the file . My idea is that i could search the document for the "Track ID" character then somehow read the number (ie Track ID=20 then read 20) and then keep the 2 columns Z(mm) and KinE. How would i go by code-wish though?

Comment: Your data seems to be fixed-width, so you could get column values via `$line.Substring($start, $length)`. add `.Trim()` to remove leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Could you provide the text file as a text and not as a picture pls?

Comment: @f6a4 Would please help me further? I have commented on your solution below. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
$content=Get-Content "C:\temp\kkk.txt"

#extract rows splited on space delimiter
$rows= $content | where {$_ -notmatch "[*]."} | select -skip 2 | %{

 $row=$_ -split ' ' | where {$_.trim() -ne ''} | %{$_.trim()}

if($row -ne $null)
{
  [pscustomobject]@{
                    Step=$row[0]
                    X=$row[1]
                    Y=$row[2]
                    Z=$row[3]
                    KinE=$row[4]
                    dE=$row[5]
                    StepLeng=$row[6]
                    TrackLeng=$row[7]
                    NextVolume=$row[8]
                    ProcName=$row[9]
                   }

}

}

#extract number searched
$Number= $content | where {$_ -like "* G4Track*"} | %{ $_ -split ',' | where {$_ -like '*Track ID = *'} | %{ ($_ -split '=')[1].Trim()}}

#extract row searched into new file csv (you can open with excel)
$rows | where Step -EQ $Number | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

This collects the needed data (Track ID, Z(mm), KinE(MeV)) and put it into a new Excel worksheet:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\kpapa\Desktop\kkk.txt'

$excelArray = New-Object 'object[,]' 1048576, 3     # 1048576 = maximum Excel rows
$row = 0                                            # row counter

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filePath) ) {

    # Track-Line => Get Track ID
    if($line -like '*Track ID*') {
       $trackID = ($line -split ',' | ? { $_ -like '*Track ID*' }).ToString() -replace '[^0-9]',''
    }
    else {
        # Value row? => Get Z(mm) and KinE(MeV)
        $tmpArray = $line -split ' ' | ? { $_ }
        if( $tmpArray.Length -gt 5 -and ( $tmpArray[0] -replace '[^0-9]' ).Length -gt 0 ) {
            $excelArray[$row,0] = $trackID
            $excelArray[$row,1] = [decimal]$tmpArray[3]   # Z(mm)
            $excelArray[$row,2] = [decimal]$tmpArray[4]   #KinE(MeV)
            $row++
        }
    }
}

# Put data to Excel...
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1).Range('A1:C' + $row.ToString() ).Value2 = $excelArray
```

Comment: This is great i really cannot thank  you enough ! I wish you could hep me on one more thing. If you take a look in the txt file there is also a parent id number. I would like to have a condition so that if a parent id equals some track id then the same rows under that specific parent id are also extracted below in the document . Also is there a way to extract each track id in different spreadsheets so that i have one spreadsheet that contains one track id number and all the parent ids' for which the parent id equals the track id?? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you left align the `NextVolume`, you might use the [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable):

```
$Particle = ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
Step#    X(mm)    Y(mm)    Z(mm) KinE(MeV)  dE(MeV) StepLeng TrackLeng  NextVolume ProcName
    0        0        0 1.08e+03      100         0        0         0  World      initStep
    1        0        0      800      100     3e-23      280       280  Tracker    Transportation
    2        0        0      450      100  3.75e-23      350       630  Film       StepLimiter    
    3        0        0      438     87.1      12.9       12       642  Film       hIoni  
    4   -0.204   -0.136      429     76.7      10.4     9.42       651  Film       hIoni
    5   -0.422   -0.104      421     67.3      9.43     7.53       659  Film       hIoni
    6   -0.679  -0.0754      415     59.3      7.94     5.98       665  Film       hIoni
    7   -0.899   -0.128      410     52.3      7.05     4.81       670  Film       hIoni
    8    -1.01   -0.141      406     45.7       6.6     3.86       674  Film       hIoni
    9    -1.04   -0.168      403     40.3      5.39     3.06       677  Film       hIoni
   10     -1.1   -0.203      401     35.3      4.96     2.47       679  Film       hIoni
   11    -1.13   -0.218      399     30.6      4.65     1.98       681  Film       hIoni
   12    -1.16   -0.191      397     26.6      4.03     1.57       683  Film       hIoni
   13    -1.21   -0.154      396     23.2       3.4     1.25       684  Film       hIoni
   14    -1.26   -0.141      395       20      3.21     1.01       685  Film       hIoni
   15     -1.3   -0.129      394     17.1       2.9    0.812       686  Film       hIoni
   16    -1.34   -0.115      394     14.4      2.74    0.651       686  Film       hIoni
   17    -1.31   -0.108      393     12.1      2.32    0.517       687  Film       hIoni
   18    -1.29    -0.12      393     9.74      2.32    0.418       687  Film       hIoni
   19    -1.28    -0.13      392     7.56      2.18    0.332       688  Film       hIoni
   20    -1.27   -0.142      392     5.41      2.15    0.261       688  Film       hIoni
   21    -1.27   -0.152      392     3.07      2.34    0.199       688  Film       hIoni
   22    -1.28   -0.156      392    0.285      2.78    0.118       688  Film       hIoni
   23    -1.28   -0.157      392        0     0.285  0.00319       688  Film       hIoni
'

PS C:\> $Particle | Where {$_.'Step#' -eq 20}

ProcName   : hIoni
Z(mm)      : 392
StepLeng   : 0.261
X(mm)      : -1.27
Y(mm)      : -0.142
dE(MeV)    : 2.15
KinE(MeV)  : 5.41
Step#      : 20
NextVolume : Film
TrackLeng  : 688
```

This works for the given example but I recommend to place separators under the headers as it might not be possible to determine the column alignement if all fields have the same width as the column header, e.g.:

```
 X(mm)
------
 -0.12
 -0.23
```

For details see: `ConvertFrom-SourceTable -?`

<sub>The [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable/0.0.32/DisplayScript) is available for download at the PowerShell Gallery and the source code from the [GitHub `iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) repository.</sub>